# ProcessBuilder working in Linux but not Windows

Tags: java, windows, ioexception, processbuilder

I have a simple program that runs the `echo` command with `ProcessBuilder`, and the program works perfectly fine on my Linux machine, but it throws an `IOException` when running on Windows.

This is a simplified version of my program. It takes `echo` and `hello` as arguments for `ProcessBuilder`, and then saves the output into a string and prints the output. In Linux, the output is `hello`, and in Windows an `IOException` is caught.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestPB {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "hello");
        try {
            Process process = pb.start();
            BufferedReader readProcessOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String output = "";
            String line = "";
            while ( (line = readProcessOutput.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line;
                output += System.getProperty("line.separator");
            }

            process.waitFor();
            if(output.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(output.substring(0, output.length() -1));
            } else {
                System.out.println("No result");
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("IOException thrown");
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is not working in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` is not a program on Windows, it's an internal shell command<sup>*</sup>, so you need to invoke the command-line interpreter:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "echo", "hello");
```

<sup>**) Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe#Windows_NT_family)*</sup>

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me - adding of "cmd.exe" as first parameter for windows OS. Because of this implementation===>Constructs a process builder with the specified operating system program and arguments. This constructor does not make a copy of the command list. Subsequent updates to the list will be reflected in the state of the process builder. It is not checked whether command corresponds to a valid operating system command.

 public ProcessBuilder(List<String> command)